# Any way to reset or reorder auto increment id (sequence) in Spring boot api

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

right now I have a class that has an id that has a sequence generator like this:

```
@Entity(name = "OU")
@Table(
    name = "OU"
)
public class OU{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "compania_sequence",
        sequenceName = "ou_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "ou_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
        nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;


    @Column(
        name = "name",
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    private String name;
```

My problem is that the user, to select this object in a GET request, passes the id as an argument in the HTTP request. So let's say that we have over 200 entries and he deletes 5 of them (randomly), then I would have 5 "empty" id positions, so I was wondering if it is possible to reorder these ids every time there is a delete request or a post request to make it easier for the user to manage them.

Another thing that I've seen is that when **I update the whole object it also increments the id** in the database, so the next id when I upload a new object is (n+1) instead of what it is supposed to be (n). Is this an error? I use

```
uoRepository.save(uo) //with the db id loaded
```

I don't know if I'm explaining it well

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of architecture this would be a bad idea. IDs should be permanently assigned. Just accept the "gaps". Reassigning freed IDs can lead to lots of problems in the future including security issues.

Comment: There is no rule that sequences should be free of gaps. Everything is fine.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks both of you, I didn't now that, I will keep it in mind